# C# Generic Generics (A Serious Question)

Tags: c#, generics, metaprogramming

In C# I am trying to write code where I would be creating a Func delegate which is in itself generic.  For example the following (non-Generic) delegate is returning an arbitrary string:

```
Func<string> getString = () => "Hello!";
```

I on the other hand want to create a generic which acts similarly to generic methods.  For example if I want a generic Func to return default(T) for a type T. I would imagine that I write code as follows:

```
Func<T><T> getDefaultObject = <T>() => default(T);
```

Then I would use it as

`getDefaultObject<string>()` which would return null and if I were to write `getDefaultObject<int>()` would return 0.

This question is not merely an academic excercise.  I have found numerous places where I could have used this but I cannot get the syntax right.  Is this possible? Are there any libraries which provide this sort of functionality?

Comment: Is there some reason that `Func<T> CreateGetDefaultObject<T>() { return () => default(T); }` won't work?

Comment: I see now. You wish to pass a compile-time type argument to a delegate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though one might find *practical workarounds* like Stephen Cleary's

```
Func<T> CreateGetDefaultObject<T>() { return () => default(T); }
```

where you can specify the generics directly, this is a quite interesting problem from a theoretical point that cannot be solved by C#'s current type system.

---

A type which, as you call it, *is in itself generic*, is referred to as a *higher-rank type*.

Consider the following example (pseudo-C#):

```
Tuple<int[], string[]> Test(Func<?> f) {
    return (f(1), f("Hello"));
}
```

In your proposed system, a call could look like that:

```
Test(x => new[] { x }); // Returns ({ 1 }, { "Hello" })
```

But the question is: How do we type the function `Test` and it's argument `f`?
Apparently, `f` maps every type `T` to an array `T[]` of this type. So maybe?

```
Tuple<int[], string[]> Test<T>(Func<T, T[]> f) {
    return (f(1), f("Hello"));
}
```

*But this doesn't work*. We can't parameterize `Test` with *any particular* `T`, since `f` should can be applied to **all** types `T`. At this point, C#'s type system can't go further.

What we needed was a notation like

```
Tuple<int[], string[]> Test(forall T : Func<T, T[]> f) {
    return (f(1), f("Hello"));
}
```

In your case, you could type

```
forall T : Func<T> getDefaultValue = ...
```

The only language I know that supports this kind of generics is Haskell:

```
test :: (forall t . t -> [t]) -> ([Int], [String])
test f = (f 1, f "hello")
```

See this Haskellwiki entry on [polymorphism](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Polymorphism) about this `forall` notation.

Comment: Thanks Dario, very interesting answer.  Although I ain't a Haskell master by any stretch, I understood your answer and the link you gave.  

As far as I understand, there is no solution/workaround as this is a limitation of the language as it does not support Rank N Types.  Perhaps in another 5 - 10 years time Microsoft will add "Rank n Types" to the CLR.

Comment: @tahirhassan: Yep, it's a quite fundamental property of the language's type system (and a quite advanced one - even Haskell does only support it by non-standard extensions) that one can't outrun. 

One possibility I see though it that you can sort-of emulate this behaviour by implementing an interface like `interface ToRankNArray { T[] Apply<T>(T arg); }`. Languages like Java or F# allow the creation of anonymous subtypes, but of course it's neither as convenient as an anonymous function nor does it change the type-system itself.

Answer (score 8):

Well you can't overload anything based only on the return value, so this includes variables.

You can however get rid of that lambda expression and write a real function:

```
T getDefaultObject<T>() { return default(T); }
```

and then you call it exactly like you want:

```
int i=getDefaultObject<int>();       // i=0
string s=getDefaultObject<string>(); // s=null
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Blindy, but the question was more about dynamically setting a Generic Generic Delegate (if that is at all possible).  The problem with your code about is that you are creating a method rather than a delegate which can declared, instantiated and used WITHIN a method.

Comment: True, but doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible, since a delegate *instance* in C# cannot have generic parameters. The closest you can get is to pass the type object as a regular parameter and use reflection. :(

In many cases, casting to **dynamic** helps remove the pain of reflection, but **dynamic** doesn't help when creating new instances, such as your example.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this, because generic type parameters have to be known at runtime. You have to use the activator class:

`Object o = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(StringBuilder));`

which will do exactly what you want to. You can write it as the following:

```
public T Default<T>()
{
  return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
}
```

**Edit**

Blindy's solution is better.